# Why can't I remove this class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a skeleton loading screen by having a class 'skeleton' on the elements which styles them then removing it with javascript after a timeout. The issue is that i can't get the javascript to work.

Here's my javascript to remove the class, why isn't it working?

```
const timeout = setTimeout(loading, 3000);

function loading() {
    const element = document.getElementById("skeleton");
    element.classList.remove("skeleton");   
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML, in case there's a clue there? Perhaps make a [mcve] with some simplified HTML, CSS, and JS that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Seems like `sketeton` is id not class

Comment: An id is not a class!

Comment: @phuzi there is an element with both a "skeleton" id and a "skeleton" class which is allowed.

Comment: @Andy True but it's likely that this is not what OP wants if it's not working.

Comment: We need to see the HTML that goes with the code.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is happening is that you have too many "skeleton" elements with the same id, and ids have to be unique. So remove the ids, and target the classes instead, and use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over each of them to remove the class.

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(loading, 3000);

function loading() {
  const skeletons = document.querySelectorAll('.skeleton');
  skeletons.forEach(skeleton => {
    skeleton.classList.remove('skeleton');
  });   
}
```

```css
.skeleton { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="skeleton">One</div>
<div class="skeleton">Two</div>
<div class="skeleton">Three</div>
<div class="skeleton">Four</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getElmentById on Class. Can You Share The HTML Elment whose id or class is skeleton
try this

```
function loading() {
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName("skeleton")[0];
    element.classList.remove("skeleton");   
  }
```